# hashchange for backbutton and ajax call

Tags: javascript, hash, back-button

Is there a way to seperate a hashchange that occurs after a

window.location.hash = 'x'

from the one that occurs after clicking the backbutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 3.6+, and Chrome 5+, you can bind callbacks to the window.onhashchange event and use it without any kind of plugin.

For those Browsers does NOT support onhashchange, you can use Jquery plugin `http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hashchange`

Comment: you're not answering my question. I want to seperate the onhashchange detection when content loads and when i click the back button. I wantit to be 2 different events.